# Combo-box items list floating on the form when mouse scrolling

Tags: delphi, scroll, combobox

The issue is related to regular `TComboBox` component.
The problem exists when accessing *drop list* from the combo-box and next when **scrolling through the form**, fields list remains in the same place. It's really annoying from the user perspective.

[image]

Is there any way to automatically lose the control focus when scrolling through the form? Any other ideas?

Please see sample code below to recreate the issue.

```
unit Unit10;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, vcl.wwcheckbox, Vcl.Mask, vcl.wwdbedit, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  vcl.wwdotdot, vcl.wwdbcomb, vcl.wwdbdatetimepicker;

type
  TForm10 = class(TForm)
    grpPanels: TCategoryPanelGroup;
    pnl1: TCategoryPanel;
    pnl2: TCategoryPanel;
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    procedure FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint;
      var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  var
  Form10 : TForm10;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm10.FormMouseWheel(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; WheelDelta: Integer; MousePos: TPoint;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
   if WheelDelta > 0 then
      grpPanels.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0)
   else
      grpPanels.Perform(WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEDOWN, 0);
end;

procedure TForm10.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
   i: Integer;
begin
   for i := 0 to 5 do
      ComboBox1.Items.Add(IntToStr(i));
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to automatically lose the control focus when scrolling through the form? Any other ideas?

Add to the beginning of `FormMouseWheel()` either of the following:

Assure the combo loses focus:

```
  if ActiveControl is TComboBox then
    FocusControl(nil);
```

Alternative,  assure the dropdown is closed, but retain focus

```
  if ActiveControl is TComboBox then
    TComboBox(ActiveControl).DroppedDown := False;
```

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution - what if there are 50 comboboxes?

Answer (score 0):

I've found another way to handle this issue and want to share it with you.
The thing is the problem also exists for other *WIN32 vcl* components like `TDateTimePicker`, `TComboBox` etc.

To handle all this cases with not losing control focus we can call `CM_CANCELMODE` message at the beginning of `FormMouseWheel()` :

```
for i := 0 to ComponentCount - 1 do
   if Components[i] is TWinControl then
      TWinControl(Components[i]).Perform(CM_CANCELMODE, 0, 0);
```